# Reading data from InputStream

Tags: java, io

When reading data from `InputStream` using API call, it seams like the stream buffer in server is filled and this overflow causes disconnection to the stream.

Is there any way to read a stream multiple threads or is there any other solution to avoid disconnection?

The following code I am using:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(inputStream, 100*1024),"utf-8"),100*1024);
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    //pooling to thread
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show us the code you use and the exception (with the full stack trace) you're getting?

Comment: Why do you think that "stream buffer" "overflow" causes a disconnect? What exception do you get and where?

Comment: That code looks fine.  What do you mean by the "pooling to thread" comment though (as you don't actually do anything with the `line` value)?  And what did you have in mind when you mentioned reading a stream in multiThread [sic], do you want multiple threads to read from the same stream concurrently?

Comment: There is no 'overflow' in evidence here, and no evidence of a disconnect either. What is your *actual problem?*